# Custom meta tag in Drupal not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, meta-tags

I wanted to add following meta tag:

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

For that I used Admin > Config > Search and Metadata > Custom Meta tags Setting

And created meta tag there.

But the meta tag is not visible in page source code in browser.

## What step am I missing?

Version: 7.35
The meta tag i added appears in list of meta tags here.

Picture: [image]

Comment: what version of Drupal do you talk about?
have you cleared cache?
Can you provide a screenshot with what you have done?

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi the picture and version are added to question. Regards

Comment: And yes the cache is cleared.

Comment: once you debug issue, please post information about it. So we can help from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way for you to find an issue.

Below you will find a screen of function that adds tags to header.

[image]

According to conditions you have possibly next issues:

1. $meta_tags is null. It means that this query return nothing

   $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {custom_meta}");
2. you have 'admin' as an argument.

Please debug those 2 variables ($meta_tags and arg(0) and provide us feedback.

```
dpm($meta_tags);
dpm(arg(0));
```

I believe you will figure out during debug the issue.